# image of a set under complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

In this exercise find and sketch the image of $|z-2|<1$ under $w=\frac{2}{z-1}$ my professor said that is sufficient to just look what happens at the boundary and where is one point inside mapped. But why does the boundary of my set goes to the boundary of the image ? And why the internal part of the set goes to internal part of image of the set? What property does this function has ?

Comment: Nonconstant analytic functions are open hence the boundary of the image of a domain under such must come from the image (in the limit if needed) of the original boundary though in general the inclusion (boundary image included image boundary) may be strict; if the function is also injective like here the inclusion becomes equality and the boundary of the image is also a Jordan curve possibly containing infinity when it becomes just a simple curve from $\infty$ to $\infty$; either way it splits the plane into two parts and again by open property the image of the original domain is one such part

Comment: @Conrad why injectivity implies equality?

Comment: because injectivity implies no boundary point is sent to the same place as an interior point so boundary points are then sent to boundary points